# Problems of inviting friends through Facebook email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, invite

I want my users to invite their friends by sending them Facebook private massage. I am thinking of using send button, but the problem is that each invitation url is different and unique, so if I use send button to do it, I might need to create many send buttons each of which carries an unique href. I think this should work? But ideally, I want users to just select their friends in a multi friend selector and everything's done by just clicking the sending button. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what?? you want to track the invitations?

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry that I can't post image here because of my reputation. Here is the link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/. what I want to do is very much like the friend-request in the above link. I want my users to select friends in the multi-friend selector dialog, and by pressing the "send request" button, message containing a href is sent to their message box. And plus each href(or url) is unique such as http://www.site.com/invite.php?token=XXXXXXXX

Comment: what do you want the token to measure? why do you need to have an uniq href?

Comment: actually for some reason, I want to restrict their invitation. I don't want the invitation to be re-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a unique URL for the message that includes the IDs for all the users the user wants to send the message to. Then, when the recipient accesses the URL and authenticates themselves, you can cross reference the URL and their User ID to what you have in your database.

Without knowing what the message contains, its purpose and what you want to achieve, this is the best approach I can think of.

You won't be able to tell who the message is actually sent to, as Facebook doesn't return the User IDs in the callback, but if you have read_inbox permissions, you should be able to look the User IDs up that way.

Comment: @DavidCheung if you think you've received an acceptable answer, please *give credits* to the answerer by flagging his/her one as *the* answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think an better way to approach this is set up an invite system, have an invitation code field in your register.php that you sign into, store that info in user account database and set an number of times it can be used